# Why send a header with status code?

Tags: php, http, web, http-status-codes

I have a page in php that I want no access to it except my application.
if there is not session predefined I sent header location.

Then I thought using

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
exit();
```

All working well and I can add my own "Unauthorized Message" I want.
But why?
I can easily not send any header (default will be 200) still with my "Unauthorized Message".

What is the point telling the browser the status code if it doesn't do anything?

**Edit:**
I want to explain myself better.
It doesn't matter if it's 404, 403 or 500. The browser will not show any message by it self, And if I won't use the exit it will keep render the rest of the page. so how it helps me to send the header?

Comment: If you tell the browser the status code, it __will__ do something, it will tell the user that their access to the page is unauthorised: likewise, it will tell other access methods (such as curl) the same thing.... but you shouldn't simply send a 401 response, but also include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource

Comment: Gil, I believe your answer lies inside the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MarkBaker the header i sent shows a white page. and if i won't use the exit() it will show the rest of the page

Comment: @gil - If you send a 401, you should also be sending a WWW-Authenticate header field, perhaps you should be sending a 403 instead, which should include a reason for rejection of the request

Comment: The header is only a line of data asking the browser to redirect. The rest of the page will still be served by PHP and can be looked at by the client by simply preventing the header command from executing.

Answer (score 2):

The 401 status code will trigger an authentication popup on client side. (The WWW-Authenticate header is also needed for this...)

Details for example here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication